# Using Java 7 Source Level in Library Projects

Tags: java, android, gradle

Using the new Gradle build tools I can set the source level of my Android code to Java 7 from Java 6.  This gives me access to a bunch of niceties like <>, string switches, and collapsable try catch.

I am working on an android library project.  If I use source level 7 in my library and the client uses source level 6 in their app, will there be a conflict?

Comment: Don't think so. Most of the cool Java 7 features (besides InvokeDynamic) are mostly compiler tricks. The bytecode should remain the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fine as long as you only use *source* level 1.7 and don't use any of the APIs introduced in Java 7 (this is why your IDE will complain if you don't have an actual Java 6 JDK if you target Java 6). Make sure to set your target level to 1.6.

Comment: So it's fine to use source level things such as collapsible catch, string switches, etc?

Comment: @jophde Sure, as long as the sugar is just a shortcut for syntax you could type more verbosely in the older version. The diamond operator is fine; `try-with-resources`, which uses a new interface (`AutoCloseable`) probably isn't, though I haven't tried it. Lambdas are right out.